# Unable to Migrate Database (tried MySQL and PostgreSQL) on Heroku

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, heroku

I am trying to run Laravel app on Heroku

I've pushed the app and configured it. But when I am trying to migrate database via using command heroku run php artisan serve it is giving following error.

> In Connection.php line 664:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_s
>     chema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations)
>
> In Connector.php line 68:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

I've made changes in .env file too for DB credentials and host.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment variables in Heroku's web admin panel

```
Go to your app in Heroku -> settings -> Reveal Config Vars
```

Then set your environment variable
Take for example

```
DB_DATABASE = your-database-name 
DB_HOST = your-database-host-name
DB_PASSWORD = your-db-password
DB_PORT = your-db-port
DB_USERNAME = your-db-username
```